# outlying data points are still being plotted after enforcing axes in matplotlib scatter3D?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm just starting to learn python, and was recently trying to make a 3D scatter plot with my dataset using matplotlib. Because my data is so spread out (x range = (1 to 20000)), I tried to enforce the X-axis limits to show just data points where x < 1000. However, when I try to set axis limits, I still see points that are greater than x=1000 on the plot. I can't really figure out why it's doing it, and couldn't find an answer by my searches on the internet :(

This is kind of a simplified example of what I did... When I enforce x-axis limits to 2, I still see the point (3,3,3) being plotted. Why is it doing this and what am I doing wrong?

THANK YOU VERY MUCH in advance!!!!

---

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

xs = [1,2,3,5,11]
ys = [1,2,3,4,5]
zs = [1,2,3,4,5]

ax.scatter3D(xs, ys, zs, c="blue")

ax.set_xlim3d([0,2])
ax.set_ylim3d([0,5])
ax.set_zlim3d([0,5])

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

plt.show()
```

Comment: This issue is being tracked here: github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25804

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim data outside 3d plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091229/trim-data-outside-3d-plot-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 1):

The following works well for me. You just had a minor bug in the set_xlim3d call. Take a look [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html) for more documentation.

```
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax  = Axes3D(fig)

xs = [1,2,3,5,11]
ys = [1,2,3,4,5]
zs = [1,2,3,4,5]

ax.scatter(xs, ys, zs, c="blue")

ax.set_xlim3d(0,2)
ax.set_ylim3d(0,5)
ax.set_zlim3d(0,5)

ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```