# Trim data outside 3d plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a set of PDF that I need to plot for a certain section of the PDF domain. However, when I plot my lines on a 3d plot I get tails for each PDF,

[image]

Is there a clean way to not plot the tails that happen outside my plot limits?  I know I can change the data to NaNs to achieve the same effect but I want to do this in matplotlib.  Here is my current workaround code,

```
`# trim the data
y = np.ones(PDF_x.shape)*PDF_x
y[y>95]= np.nan
y[y<75]= np.nan


# plot the data
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
for i in range(PDF_capacity.shape[1]):
    ax.plot(life[i]*np.ones((PDF_x.shape)),y,PDF_capacity[:,i], label='parametric curve')

# set the axis limits
ax.set_ylim(75,95)

# add axis labels
ax.set_xlabel('charge cycles to failure point of 75% capacity')
ax.set_ylabel('capacity at 100 charge cycles')
ax.set_zlabel('probability')`
```

After trimming I can make the following plot,

[image]

Comment: Are there any plot properties that will limit the data plotted? Like xlim or ylim?

Comment: I don't see any reason not to use the masking with `nan`s you already have (`y[y>95]= np.nan`). "I want to" is not a very good argument for convincing someone to put a lot of effort into something that already has a drawback-free one-liner solution.

Comment: I am using `ax.set_ylim(75,95)` to restrict the plot to the stated limits, however, this does not trim the data to between these limits.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest , If you do not think it is possible within matplotlib maybe we could just us that as the solution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is possible, but I don't think it's worth the effort as the solution would probably not be general and would involve a deep dive into the matplotlib code.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest If you want to copy and past your opinion that there is not a "clean way" to trim the plot I can mark this question as answered. This was my question so I think it makes sense to close out the question for now.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25804

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Masking the data with `nan` in the way you're doing it is a good and practical solution.

Since matplotlib 3D plots are projections into 2D space, it would be hard to implement automatic clipping. While I do think it would be possible, I'm not convinced that it's worth the effort. First, because you would need to treat different kinds of plots differently, second, because at least in some cases it would probably turn out that masking the data is still the best choice. Now, doing a complex subclassing of the plotting objects just to do the same thing that can be manually done in one or two lines is probably overkill.

My clear recommendation would therefore be to use the solution you already have. Especially since it does not seem to have any drawbacks so far.