# How to stop line plots from exceeding x and y limits when plotting in 3D Plot using Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using Matplot to  plot a 3D surface of a function with 4 lines on the XY plane representing the region of integration. However even though I am setting the x and y limits the line still extends beyond the limit but I am not sure why. How do I set limits such that the line stops at the end of the defined x and y limit? (see image of current and ideal plot)

```
# Plot Surface with Region R

# Create plot area
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))
ax = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1, projection = '3d')

# On first subplot, plot 3D surface of f1 = x**2*y**4 with Region R
x = np.linspace(0.001, 5, 100)
y = np.linspace(0.001, 10, 100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = X**2*Y**4

# Plot function
surf = ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z, rstride= 2, cstride=2, cmap = cm.coolwarm, linewidth = 0, alpha =0.7)

# Set limits
ax.set_xlim(0.001, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0.001, 10)

# y = 6x
ax.plot(x,6*x, color = "red")

# y = 4/x
ax.plot(x, 4/x, c = "blue", clip_on = true)

# y = 10/x
ax.plot(x, 10/x, c = "green")

# y = x
ax.plot(x, x, c = "orange")

# Set axis labels
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")
ax.set_zlabel("z")
```

This is as far as I can get
[image]

This is the part of the line extending beyond the y axis I want to get rid of, highlighted in black

[image]

Comment: It's a bug in matplotlib's 3D plotting library. Rotate the output and see that the line changes boundaries and even its form. I would not know how to prevent this.

Comment: As a workaround, I had a thought of limiting the array representing the x values so they only include values where y < y_limit and x< x_limit but would not be sure how to implement this.

Comment: This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25804

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim data outside 3d plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091229/trim-data-outside-3d-plot-in-matplotlib)