# How do I remove overflow along the z-axis for a 3D matplotlib surface?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to graph a 3d mesh surface with matplotlib and constrain the limits of the graph.  The X and Y axes are correctly constrained, but there is overflow in the Z-Axis.

What am I missing?  Here's my code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

x = np.linspace(-6,6,100)
y = np.linspace(-6,6,100)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

def f(x,y):
    return x**2 + 3*y

Z = f(X,Y)


ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,Z,cmap='viridis')

ax.title.set_text("z=x**2+3y")
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')

ax.set_zlim3d(zmin=-3,zmax=5)
ax.set_xlim3d(xmin=-6,xmax=6)
ax.set_ylim3d(ymin=-6,ymax=6)

plt.show()
```

The graph:

[image: Overflowing graph]

Edit:

When I add clipping/min/max to the Z values, the graph is a little better, but it sets z values outside the bounds to the bounds themselves.  Both of the following suggestions do this.  Perhaps it's because I'm on a mac?

```py
z_tmp = np.maximum(np.minimum(5,Z),-3)
```

```py
z_temp = np.clip(Z, -3, 5, None)
```

[image: better graph]

Comment: `ax.set_zlim3d(zmin=18,zmax=54)` ?? Z values are not within -3 and 5

Comment: This issue is being tracked here: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/25804

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trim data outside 3d plot in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44091229/trim-data-outside-3d-plot-in-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data is outside the axis boundaries. Try rotate the view and you will notice.

```py
z = x**2 + 3*y
```

If you want to only show a defined area of the data you could add a max() min() limitation on the Z data to exclude the data outside your wanted limitations.

```py
Z = f(X,Y)

z_tmp = np.maximum(np.minimum(5,Z),-3)


ax = plt.axes(projection = '3d')
ax.plot_surface(X,Y,z_tmp,cmap='viridis')
```

I'm not sure the matplotlib behaves as it should in your default case.

Comment: numpy.clip(a, a_min, a_max, out=None, **kwargs) should work fine aswell.

Comment: It definitely looks nicer with both of these answers, but instead of totally removing the points, it just sets overflowing Z value for the points to those mins and maxes.

I wish I could post an image in the comments, but an example would be for x=6, y=6, it renders a point at (6,6,5)

Comment: Perhaps it's because I'm on a mac?

Comment: Edited my answer w/ the results